# Possible Conference Speaking Sponsorships -- 2011

Tags: discussion, speakers-bureau, sponsorship, conferences

We're evaluating the feasibility of **sponsoring a member of the TeX community to speak at a conference in 2011**.

Speaking is a relatively big "ask", so this needs to be planned many months in advance. Let's get started!

We'd like the community to establish **where** ...

> What relevant TeX conferences are coming up in 2011 that have open speaker slots or calls for papers?

... and then **who**.

> Which members of the community are strongly interested in being sponsored by Stack Exchange, Inc to speak at one of the above conferences in 2011?

To be clear, the speaker is free talk about anything he or she wants so long as it would be roughly on topic for this site -- with a quick acknowledgement of support from Stack Exchange and a mention of the community here.

Comment: It's worth looking at how the tcs.sx folk went about promoting themselves [at FOCS](http://meta.cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/457/nominations-for-publicity-poster-at-focs), where they prosented a poster with the most attractive questions and scientifically interesting answers, and their plans for presenting [at the giant FCRC](http://meta.cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/1045/promoting-tcs-se-at-fcrc).

Comment: What kind of thing might sponsoring cover?  E.g., I expect that travel costs to Kerala, India would be a big deal for Americans & Europeans considering attending.

Comment: @charles I believe that is all negotiable, but travel costs and conference costs would certainly be covered.

Comment: I'm too busy with my studies at the moment, otherwise I would really think about it. Let's hope you repeat this next year.

Answer (score 17):

### TeX Conferences in 2011

- [5th International ConTeXt Meeting](http://meeting.contextgarden.net/2011/): Bassenge-Boirs, Belgium, September 19–24, 2011
- [TeXperience 2011](http://striz9.fame.utb.cz/texperience/): Zelezna Ruda, Czech Republic, September 28-October 2, 2011
- [Autumn 2011 Meeting](http://www.dante.de/events/mv45.html) of DANTE, the German TeX Users Group: Garmisch-Partenkirchen, Germany, September 30-October 1
- [TUG 2011](http://tug.org/tug2011/), meeting of the TeX Users Group: Trivandrum, Kerala, India, October 19-21, 2011

For information only, since deadline is passed, but upcoming:

- [EuroBachoTeX 2011](http://www.gust.org.pl/bachotex/bachotex2011-en): Bachotek, Poland, April 29-May 3, 2011

I mean, the TUG 2011 is the most important one.

Answer (score 11):

Thank you for the kind offer. Here we are.

### Speaking at the TUG Conference 2011

Done for now:

- Chosen the most important conference, which is the [Annual Meeting of the TeX Users Group](http://tug.org/tug2011/), held for the 32nd time
- Discussed who is interested to [go to the conference](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1497/who-plans-to-go-to-the-tug-2011-conference-in-india) and who likes to speak, one of our moderators volunteered.
- Chosen a topic which is a very good fit to represent our site:

  **TeX online - from Usenet to Web 2.0 and beyond**
- Sent an abstract to the organisers for the [Call for Papers](http://tug.org/tug2011/cfp.html)

  > **Bringing together TeX users online - from Usenet to Web 2.0 and beyond**
  >
  > It all began in the 1980s with mailing lists such as texhax and the Usenet.
  >   The online discussion board comp.text.tex emerged around 1990, where TeX
  >   hackers gathered and still populate it today.
  >
  > On the continuously developing Internet, TeX user groups created
  >   mailing lists, built homepages and software archives. Web forums
  >   turned up and lowered the barrier for beginners and occasional TeX
  >   users for getting support.
  >
  > Today, TeX's friends can also follow blogs, news feeds, and take part
  >   in vibrant question and answer sites.
  >
  > In this talk we will look at present online TeX activities.
- The presentation has been accepted and is now included in the [TUG 2011 - Program & participants](http://tug.org/tug2011/program.html).

It may be a good fit to [Community Conference Sponsorships](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/02/community-conference-sponsorships/). It's a good opportunity to meet people of the international [TeX Users Group](http://tug.org/), of the Indian TeX users group and of River Valley Technologies, who host the conference and who also host recordings of a lot of conferences on [river-valley.zeeba.tv](http://river-valley.zeeba.tv/).

Comment: awesome! kudos, and I think this may be the first speaker's bureau success story, hopefully first of many more to come. :)