# Who plans to go to the TUG 2011 conference in India?

Tags: discussion, tug, speakers-bureau, conferences

[TUG 2011](http://tug.org/tug2011/), this years meeting of the [TeX Users Group](http://tug.org/) will be in Trivandrum, Kerala, India, from October 19 to October 21.

Who will to go there? Does anybody even plan to speak?

Comment: This was one of the more popular examples of an off-topic question on [a51]: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/2148/tex-latex-and-friends/4333#4333 ... good thing there's meta `;-)`

Comment: I would love to go to one TUG meeting, but India is a little bit too far. I'm returning to Germany in the next couple of month and hope to at least go to one of the local meetings there. Would be great to see some of you in person.

Comment: can you tell me how many people will be at this conference?

Comment: @Jin I know of 48 participants according to http://tug.org/tug2011/program.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't know yet if my time will allow it, that primarily depends on my present employer. I have been considering speaking for some time.

Abstract:

> **Bringing together TeX users online - from Usenet to Web 2.0 and beyond**
>
> It all began with the Usenet, around 1980. The online discussion board
>   comp.text.tex emerged, where TeX hackers gathered and still populate
>   it today.
>
> On the continuously developing Internet, TeX user groups created
>   mailing lists, built homepages and software archives. Web forums
>   turned up and lowered the barrier for beginners and occasional TeX
>   users for getting support.
>
> Today, TeX's friends can also follow blogs, news feeds, and take part
>   in vibrant question and answer sites.
>
> In this talk we will look at present online TeX activities.

Experienced TeXnicians and Usenet users could be introduced to the vibrant world of forums, Q&A sites and user (groups) blogs, whereas younger fellow TeXnicians can learn about the big merits of Usenet. All of the online projects contribute to the success of TeX today.

TeX.SX would be an important part of the presentation, being a new and distinctive TeX community project.

Comment: related to http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1265/possible-conference-speaking-sponsorships-2011 yes? That seems like a good fit.

Comment: @Jeff: yes, it's related.